# How to define CKEditor5 two-way converter with view defined as RegExp or function?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, rich-text-editor, ckeditor5

I'd like to create plugin which allows on many values, which are considered as range not a list.
So I thought, that I could use [`attributeToElement`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_conversion-Conversion.html#function-attributeToElement), but it seems to accept only specific values, which are kept in object, what is not possible for my case. I wonder how to define view elements with entire range of possible values (in my case colors). I thought about matching them with some sort of RegExp or function. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it seems to be not possible to use [`attributeToElement`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_conversion-Conversion.html#function-attributeToElement) converter provided with CKEditor5. This converter needs to have limited predefined amount of options provided for conversion, which will be used for both `upcast` and `downcast`.

From perspective of plugin which I want to write (color font) it's not sufficient. I don't want to limit model to accept only few colors and prevent of using different one.

To have more control over `upcast` and `downcast` is necessary to write own functions which will cover such cases. And which will be able to accept any color inserted to editor. To do so it's required to use [`for`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_conversion-Conversion.html#function-for) method. Below you can find some simple solution which will accept colors defined in hex and upcast it to model. And another function which will downcast it to view.

### Upcast:

```
editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' ).elementToAttribute( {
    view: {
        name: 'span',
        styles: {
            'color': /#\d+/
        }
    },
    model: {
        key: 'color',
        value: viewElement => {
            const color = viewElement.getStyle( 'color' );
            return color.replace( '#', '' );
        }
    }
} );
```

### Downcast:

```
editor.conversion.for( 'downcast' ).attributeToElement( {
    model: 'color',
    view: ( modelAttributeValue, viewWriter ) => viewWriter.createAttributeElement( 'span', {
        style: 'color:#' + modelAttributeValue
    } );
} );
```