# Adding classes to links in CKeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I have some specific requirements around adding classes to links in ckeditor5 - I have read the docs and tried numerous approaches but I'm still struggling to achieve what I want here. My requirements are:

1. All links added (whether using the link UI, or via paste) must have a class assigned. That class should be set to `defaultClass` if no class is assigned or the class assigned is not in the list of valid classes
2. Link classes must be in the list of valid link classes

I have built a dropdown containing a list of the valid classes and added it to the link interface[image: Link class dropdown]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    const { editor } = this

    const linkClasses = editor.config.get('link.options.classes')
    const defaultLinkClass = editor.config.get('link.options.defaultClass')

    editor.model.schema.extend('$text', { allowAttributes: 'linkClass' })

    editor.conversion.for('downcast').attributeToElement({
      model: 'linkClass',
      view: (attributeValue, writer) => writer.createAttributeElement('a', { class: attributeValue }, { priority: 5 }),
      converterPriority: 'low'
    })

    editor.conversion.for('upcast').attributeToAttribute({
      view: {
        name: 'a',
        key: 'class'
      },
      model: 'linkClass',
      converterPriority: 'low'
    })
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the ckeditor version 5? It does not look like the `editor` api is existing anymore https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/

Comment: It definitely is version 5 @oktapodia you can see here where I've based my code from: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/blob/master/src/linkediting.js

Comment: @PaulOdeon: Please check the `decorators` in Links in `CK Editor 5`. For more please check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to the solution is in the upcast converter - I eventually stumbled on to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55019124/803804

This led me to realise you can pass a callback into the attributeToAttribute converter https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_upcasthelpers-UpcastHelpers.html#function-attributeToAttribute

Really simple in the end:

```
editor.conversion.for('upcast').attributeToAttribute({
  view: {
    name: 'a',
    key: 'class'
  },
  model: {
    key: 'linkClass',
    value: viewElement => {
      if(this.classes.includes(viewElement.getAttribute('class'))) {
        return viewElement.getAttribute('class')
      } else {
        return this.defaultClass
      }
    }
  },
  converterPriority: 'low'
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `callback` function in `decorators` and inside the `callback`, use `setTimeout` function to check the valid class list in the `urls`.

Check the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nishalkr93/Lpsoyukz/). Refer [CKEditor5 manual decorators in Links](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/link.html#adding-attributes-to-links-using-the-ui-manual-decorators) for more and please confirm the [`Link`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_link_link-Link.html) plugin installed `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link`

Hope this will help.

Thank You

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't use the decorators as I wanted a dropdown rather than toggle switches - also I don't believe setTimeout is ideal, with CK I think we should be manipulating the model directly

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to define custom class, look for **Custom Editor JS Styles Set** in the field configuration and enter a path for .js file.

In this file you can define your custom styles like this:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add
( 'mystyles', 
    [ 
        { name: 'Bootstrap Blockquote', 
          element: 'blockquote', 
          attributes: { 'class': 'blockquote' }
        },
    ] 
);
```

Also make sure you have **Styles** toolbar item enabled

You should also check out styling using the Styles features of the editor [here](https://github.com/processwire/processwire/blob/master/wire/modules/Inputfield/InputfieldCKEditor/README.md#custom-editor-js-styles-set)

Comment: This is ck4 I believe